# How to formalize this problem on conditional probability involving $P(A|B\cap C)$?

Tags: probability, proof-verification, conditional-probability

I'm attempting a solution to the following problem, copied verbatim from my problem set. (Apparently the problem comes from [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=264_DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA45&dq=%22two%20weather%20stations%20issue%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAg-6_4cDdAhVDJt8KHfz_CsQQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22two%20weather%20stations%20issue%22&f=false).)

> Every evening, two weather stations
>   issue weather forecast for the next day. The weather forecasts are
>   independent. **On average, the weather forecast of station 1 is correct
>   90% of the cases, irrespective of weather type; this percentage is 80%
>   for station 2.** Suppose that, without any forecast, **the belief is that
>   the next day rains or has sunny weather each with a 50% chance.** On a
>   given day, station 1 predicts sunny weather for the next day, whereas
>   station 2 predicts rain. What is the probability that the weather
>   forecast of station 1 will be correct?

I understand the problem is supposed to test my comprehension of conditional probability. But I'm having trouble formalizing the information. Here is my attempt.

Let

- $S$ denote the event "tomorrow it will, in fact, be sunny"
- $R=S^c$ denote the event "tomorrow it will, in fact, rain"

Then the *second* bolded sentence means the unconditional probabilities are $P(S)=P(R)=0.5$.

What does the *first* bolded sentence mean? I guess it means

$$P(S\,|\,\text{Station 1 predicts sun})=0.9$$
$$P(R\,|\,\text{Station 1 predicts rain})=0.9$$
$$P(S\,|\,\text{Station 2 predicts sun})=0.8$$
$$P(R\,|\,\text{Station 2 predicts rain})=0.8$$

Then, I think the question is asking for the value of

$$P(S\,|\,\text{Station 1 predicts sun and Station 2 predicts rain})$$

If this is correct, I know that by the definition of conditional probablity the result is

$$\frac{P(S\,\text{and Station 1 predicts sun and Station 2 predicts rain})}{P(\text{Station 1 predicts sun and Station 2 predicts rain})}$$

But  I don't know how to proceed from here. Even if I use "the weather forecasts are independent" to conclude that the denominator factors, I don't know the probability that Station 1 predicts sun; indeed it doesn't seem like that event is stochastic, so it doesn't have a probability.

So I think my setup must be wrong.

Comment: Can you calculate $P(S\,\text{and Station 1 predicts sun and Station 2 predicts rain})$?  If so and similarly $P(R\,\text{and Station 1 predicts sun and Station 2 predicts rain})$ then the denominator is the sum of these

Comment: @Henry: I don't know how I'd calculate those: can you give me a hint?

Comment: Should the "correctness" statements instead be formalized as $P(\text{Station 1 predicts sun}\,|\,S)=0.9$, etc.? Because then I can get intersections by multiplying by $P(S)$.